# How to resume a thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm using three threads in my code.When i press 'stop' button it should stop and 'start' button should resume them..here is my code :

```
 private void jButton_stopActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    boolean result = value;
    if(result){
        t.stop();
        timer.stop();
        timer2.stop();
        value = false;
        jButton_stop.setText("Start");
    }
    else{
        t.resume();
        timer.resume();
        timer2.resume();
        value = true;
        jButton_stop.setText("Stop");
    }
```

But when i click the 'stop' button all the threads are stopped perfectly,but when i press 'start' button threads are not resuming .why?? please help me.

Comment: What do you mean by "thread"? I don't see any thread code in there. Do you mean instead a Swing Timer? I assume that you would never call `stop()` and `resume()` on a Thread.

Comment: `thread.stop()` and `resume()` are deprecated and should not used.  You should consider having the thread `wait()` on a lock `Object` and then `notify()` it to have it continue to run.

Comment: Where's the definition of `timer` and `timer2`?

Comment: The dual of `Thread#resume()` is `Thread#suspend()`, not `Thread#stop()`.  But also read the Javadoc for `Thread#suspend()`, as it will be nigh impossible to get this to work without deadlock in a program that isn't lock free.  If you post the code for the `run()` method the thread is using, I'm sure folks can suggest a possible restructure to make things work sensibly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering `t` is an instance of `Thread`:

> It is never legal to start a thread more than once. **In particular, a thread may not be 
>   restarted once it has completed execution.**

from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

And, `Thread.stop()` is deprecated.

The thread itself should check if it needs to finish, like a `boolean run` variable being checked, or using objects for thread communication.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep it on waiting based on some boolean value, for example:

```
 public void run() {
      try {
      for(int i = 15; i > 0; i--) {
         System.out.println(name + ": " + i);
         Thread.sleep(200);
         synchronized(this) {
            while(suspendFlag) {
               wait();
            }
          }
        }
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         System.out.println(name + " interrupted.");
      }
      System.out.println(name + " exiting.");
   }
```

Here you can change suspendFlag status outside thread. see [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_thread_control.htm)